# Using foreach in codeigniter view to generate select options

Tags: php, codeigniter

I ma using codeigniter to generate some html options,but i only get one result,first result from the table.

This is my controller

```
public function edit_event($id = 0){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $current_id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
    $data['data'] = $this->as->the_event_edit($id);
    $data['groups'] = $this->as->the_groups_list($current_id);
    $this->load->view('editevent',$data);
    }
```

This is my model

```
public function the_groups_list($current_id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('all_groups', array('group_owner' => $current_id));
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
    $data = array(
               'group_title' => $row->group_title,
               'group_name' => $row->group_name,
               'group_owner' => $row->group_owner
          );  
          return $data;
    }
    }
```

This is the other model

```
public function as_event_edit($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('all_scheduled_messages', array('id' => $id));
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
    $data = array(
               'as_title' => $row->as_title,
               'as_event_name' => $row->as_event_name,
               'as_owner' => $row->as_owner,
               'as_type' => $row->as_type,
               'as_target_dataset' => $row->as_target_dataset,
               'as_timestamp' => $row->as_timestamp,
               'as_time' => $row->as_time,
               'as_day' => $row->as_day
          );  
          return $data;
    }
    }
```

I am then using `$groups['group_title']` in view and only the first group title gets displayed even though i have like 4 group titles from the other rows.

How can i return and pass an array that i can then to the view so as to use foreach to iterate and display the group titles?.

Comment: use `$data[] = array(....` instead of `$data = array(`

Comment: How should i access that inside a view?

Answer (score 0):

Change the model from `$data =` to `$data[] =` to insert each row and not only one.

In your view loop over the groups, like so:

```
foreach ($data as $group) {
    echo "Title" . $groups['group_title'];
}
```

---

**RTM: [Adding Dynamic Data to the View](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)**

In the controller: rename your $data['data'] to $data['event']

```
$data['event'] = $this->as->the_event_edit($id);
$data['groups'] = $this->as->the_groups_list($current_id);
$this->load->view('editevent',$data);
```

In your view:

```
foreach ($event as $items) {
    var_dump($items);
}

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    var_dump($group);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention i had another line passing some other data into the view `$data['data'] = $this->as->the_event_edit($id);`

Answer (score 0):

In your model you're not creating a multi-dimensional array. You need to add keys either using a counter:

```
$data = array();
$i=0;
foreach ($query->result() as $row){

  $data[$i]['as_title'] = $row->as_title;
  $data[$i]['as_event_name'] = $row->as_event_name;
  $data[$i]['as_owner'] = $row->as_owner;
  $data[$i]['as_type'] = $row->as_type;
  $data[$i]['as_target_dataset'] = $row->as_target_dataset;
  $data[$i]['as_timestamp'] = $row->as_timestamp;
  $data[$i]['as_time'] = $row->as_time;
  $data[$i]['as_day'] = $row->as_day;

  $i++;

);  
return $data;
```

or use the key of the incoming array

```
$data = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $id => $row){

  $data[$id]['as_title'] = $row->as_title;
  $data[$id]['as_event_name'] = $row->as_event_name;
  $data[$id]['as_owner'] = $row->as_owner;
  $data[$id]['as_type'] = $row->as_type;
  $data[$id]['as_target_dataset'] = $row->as_target_dataset;
  $data[$id]['as_timestamp'] = $row->as_timestamp;
  $data[$id]['as_time'] = $row->as_time;
  $data[$id]['as_day'] = $row->as_day;

);  
return $data;
```